# windows bootstrap loader lost

Tags: grub2, windows-7, bootloader

I recently formatted my windows and re-installed it in a separate partition. Then I deleted the recovery partition. Now when I rebooted my system, it did not show any grub menu. Then I booted the system using a live CD and updated grub as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432). Now I dont see any option of booting in Windows. Please help.

[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1545978/) is the output of boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

Some files are missing in Windows. I guess either the ESP or the boot partition has been deleted.

**Solution:**

1. Format your disc and reinstall Windows
2. Don't delete any partition, just **reduce your main Windows partition** to 60GB.
3. Install Ubuntu **64bit** (32bit is not compatible with UEFI) following the 1st paragraph of the [UEFI Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).
4. If any problem, indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.